# How to solve the slow transition between pages in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

In my Phonegap app I have 2 pages(main , form Page) When I navigate from  the Main Page to the Form page it takes too time to Show the Form Page ,I am not added any  java script code ,this is my jsfiddle contains my form page code [JSFiddle][1] . Is there any thing wrong in my form page which slow the transition ? How can i speed up the transition ? please help me since I am new in jQuery mobile .

Thanks in advance.

Main Page

```
 <html>
  <head>  
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />  
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,          minimum-scale=1, width=device-width,height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

   <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
   <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"     rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <div data-role="page"    id="Main" >
    <div data-role="header"  data-theme="b" > </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <a href="Form.html" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-theme="none"                       data-corners="false"><img src="images/profile.png"   /></a><BR><BR><BR>
    <font color="white"  size="6px"  >  Profile </font>
    </div>

     </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 7):

I call this function at the beginning of every app I make with Jquery Mobile and it really speeds things up.

```
function optimizeSpeed() {
var hoverDelay = $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;

$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
$.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
}
```

Not part of your question, but Jquery Mobile also works faster when you bind to the 'tap' events or especially the 'touchstart' event on button presses.

Comment: @XenocideaeThanks for helping me I have tried it  with 'touchstart' event on button presses. but the transition still slow ! is there another solution ? can you help me more please since this  unfortunately didn't work for me ?

Comment: @Xenocidae, don't you have problems with the tap event? For me and for ithers tap trigger two click events, AFAIK it is a bug at least until cordova 3.0. How are you dealing with that? I would love to move to taps instead of clicks.

Comment: @user it was setting the above transitions to `none` that made a huge difference for me. Once I did that, using `touchstart` further improves performance (practically instantaneous for me).

Comment: @VicM hmm, I've never had an issue with two events being triggered. I started with phonegap 3.0 and am currently using 3.3, so that might be it.

Comment: @Xenocideae,The form page didn't show directly for me , after pressing the button it waits for few seconds  then the form page shown

Comment: Can I define it to all functions somehow? I'm using pagecreate, page before show for different pages. To put it in each page??

Comment: It makes my site go so fast! almost too fast:) Thanks!!